# Word - Copy image size

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm inserting different images into Word and giving them all the same custom size. Using format painter I can't change their size all at once, I have to do it separately.

Does anyone know how I could do this quicker? Like copy the size an image that's already been changed to a different image that needs to be resized?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Word is not an image processing engine; sure, it has some nice features, but, in all, it is used just to display, arrange, and lightly modify images.  Your choices are, from what I can see:

- **Batch Resize**: Use a utility to batch resize the images you want, prior to inserting them into Word.

I can't really think of another method, personally; if you want the pictures all the same size, it is best to process them FIRST, and then insert them second.

Would recommend you take a quick look at [IrfanView](https://lifehacker.com/345755/batch-resize-images-with-irfanview), nice easy to use free utility that can do the batch re-sizing for you; you then can just insert into word via the converted files, and not have to worry about the sizes.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I will try this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how many images you have and the order of your process, it's possible to redo the last action by pressing F4. This seems to be a good candidate for your case because you mentioned format painter.

So assuming you have already inserted all the images, I have found that these three steps to be sufficient in most of my situations. The steps are:

1. format the size of one image
2. click on another image
3. press F4

Comment: That also works good!